# How can Floquet be used to solve periodic linear equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions, homogeneous-equation

I generally understand how to solve linear systems using `x' = Ax` where x is a vector, and A is a matrix. However, I am lost when the A matrix becomes periodic. I am going to give an example, and show what my professor explained was the correct answer, but there are certain gaps in my knowledge.

Given the equation

x<sub>1</sub>' = (1+cos(t)/(2+sin(t)))x<sub>1</sub> 
x<sub>2</sub>' = 2x<sub>1</sub> - x<sub>2</sub>

I understand that the A(t) matrix would be 
$\begin{bmatrix}(1+cos(t)/(2+sin(t))) & 0\\2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$

Making it so that technically the eigen values would be (1+cos(t)/(2+sin(t))) and -1 
However, my professor then goes on to explain what x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> is and I am totally lost on how to get there.

x<sub>1</sub> = c<sub>1</sub>e<sup>t</sup>(2+sin(t)) 
x<sub>2</sub> = c<sub>1</sub>e<sup>t</sup>[(2/5)(2sin(t)-cos(t)+2] + c<sub>2</sub>e<sup>-t</sup>

Which would then lead to the X matrix where X is defined as 
$\begin{bmatrix}e^t(2+sin(t)) & 0\\e^t[(2/5)(2sin(t)-cos(t)+2] & e^{-t}\end{bmatrix}$

I was thinking that when x<sub>1</sub> = 0, that x<sub>2</sub>' + x<sub>2</sub> = 0, therefore x<sub>2</sub> = e<sup>-t</sup> which would make part of the X matrix make sense. However, I am completely lost on how x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> are found. If someone could explain to me how Floquet is used to find the matrix X that would be so helpful. Thank you.